# OpenCV fill holes in contours

Tags: python, opencv

What I am trying to do is basically the same as erode/dilate, but instead of an image, I have contours. That way, I am trying to fill in hole-like indents in the contours. (see the image below - contours drawn in red; EDIT: I have drawn them filled to show what is outside and what is inside)

[image: holes in contours]

I am aware of approxPolyDP, which I am already using, but if I give that a higher value, details in other places are lost.

Therefore, I was wondering if there are functions analogous to erode/dilate, or if I have to generate an image from the contours which I can then use to do exactly that or something similar.

EDIT: What I currently have is:

- detect contours in a binary image: `contours = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)[0]`
- approximate contours: `approxConts = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.002*cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True) for cont in contours]` (0.002 is a good value for my use case in general, higher values cause a loss of details)

What I now want to do is something like `cv2.erode(cv2.dilate(contour, someKernel), someKernel)`, which obviously doesn't work since contours aren't an image. Therefore, I need some similar function which enlarges the contours, removes lines that cross each other and instead use only the intersection point, and shrink the contours again. What I want to get is something like this:

[image: filled holes]

Comment: Please clarify further and show some code. Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to fill the whole image with blue? I do not see any contour outlines, unless you have filled them. A larger image and more background information would make your question clearer. If you have drawn the outer contours and not any inner ones, then you would have to draw and fill them and then fill any other holes as you have suggested, as far as I understand contours. They are just outlines.

Comment: You may be looking for [cv2.convexHull()](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#convexity-defects)

Comment: @nathancy not exactly what I want, but I can probably work with that... my only problem is when I have something eg. shaped like an L, this will not quite work